# Spark Jobs final status is failed in yarn-cluster mode if no spark session is created inside the class

Tags: java, apache-spark, hadoop-yarn, hadoop2

I have one situation where in if a certain condition is not meet, then there is no need to create a spark session inside the class and application exits with a messsage.

I am submitting job as below in "yarn-cluster" mode

```
spark2-submit --class com.test.TestSpark --master yarn --deploy-mode client /home/test.jar false
```

The final status of the job is `"failed"`.

But if same is run in "yarn-client" mode the spark job completes successfully.

Below is the code:

```
package com.test;

import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession;

public class TestSpark {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        boolean condition = false;
        condition = Boolean.parseBoolean(args[0]);
        if(condition){
            SparkSession sparkSession = SparkSession.builder().appName("Data Ingestion Framework")
                    .config("hive.metastore.warehouse.dir", "/user/hive/warehouse").config("spark.sql.warehouse.dir", "/user/hive/warehouse")
                    .enableHiveSupport()
                    .getOrCreate();
        }else{
        System.out.println("coming out no processing required");
        }

    }

}
```

In the logs for "`yarn-cluster`" i can see two conatiners are getting created and one of them fails with below error:

```
18/05/09 18:21:51 WARN security.UserGroupInformation: PriviledgedActionException as:*****<uername> (auth:SIMPLE) cause:java.io.FileNotFoundException: File does not exist: hdfs://hostname/user/*****<uername>/.sparkStaging/application_1525778267559_0054/__spark_conf__.zip
Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: File does not exist: hdfs://hostname/user/*****<uername>/.sparkStaging/application_1525778267559_0054/__spark_conf__.zip
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem$20.doCall(DistributedFileSystem.java:1257)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem$20.doCall(DistributedFileSystem.java:1249)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystemLinkResolver.resolve(FileSystemLinkResolver.java:81)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.getFileStatus(DistributedFileSystem.java:1249)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster$$anonfun$4$$anonfun$apply$3.apply(ApplicationMaster.scala:198)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster$$anonfun$4$$anonfun$apply$3.apply(ApplicationMaster.scala:195)
        at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:257)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster$$anonfun$4.apply(ApplicationMaster.scala:195)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster$$anonfun$4.apply(ApplicationMaster.scala:160)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster$$anon$4.run(ApplicationMaster.scala:787)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1920)
```

Could you please explain why this is happening and how does spark handles the container creation.

Comment: Is your Namenode configured as HA ?

Comment: Yes @Mervyn, the NameNode is configured as HA.

Answer (score 0):

Amit, this is a known issue that is still open.
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-10795

The workaround is to have a SparkContext initialized.

```
package com.test;
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext;
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession;

public class TestSpark {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        boolean condition = false;
        condition = Boolean.parseBoolean(args[0]);
        if(condition){
            SparkSession sparkSession = SparkSession.builder().appName("Data Ingestion Framework")
                    .config("hive.metastore.warehouse.dir", "/user/hive/warehouse").config("spark.sql.warehouse.dir", "/user/hive/warehouse")
                    .enableHiveSupport()
                    .getOrCreate();
        }else{
            // Initialize a spark context to avoid failure : https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-10795
            JavaSparkContext sparkContext = new JavaSparkContext(new SparkConf());
            System.out.println("coming out no processing required");
        }

    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the JIRA. The workaround I have already used in my code. But my concern was, if there is no need of processing using spark context then why to create it. trying to find out the possible reason why it does happen.